# Find the point on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ closest to the line given by $y=4-\sqrt{3}x$ using multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Question is: Find the point on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ closest to the line given by $y=4-\sqrt{3}x$ using multivariable calculus.

I know the shortest distance is the distance between the center and its orthogonal projection on the line minus the radius.

So this could be translated to(i think):

$\vert \frac{\sqrt{3}x+y-4}{2} \vert$, and then i have to study the critical points of this function, is this correct? and how do i get rid of the absolute value?

I cannot use Lagrange Multipliers either.

Comment: If you want to do this using straight up algebra, then construct a line from the center of the circle that is perpendicular to your target.  If the goal is to use multivariate calculus, then take the gradient.

Comment: I'm supposed to use multivariable calculus, I'm sorry, but the gradient of what?

Comment: If you take the gradient of the circle, and the line, when the two gradients are parallel, then you have found the correct direction.  Or if you take the gradient of your distance function the gradient will point in the direction of greatest change.  By the way your distance function should be $\frac {|ax + by - d|}{\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}} = \frac {|x\sqrt 3 + y - 4|}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By gradients we need to set that they are parallel that is

$$(\sqrt 3,1)=\lambda(2x,2y)\implies x=\sqrt 3 y$$

and by equality of the tangents we have

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}=-\sqrt 3\implies x=\sqrt 3 y$$

thus in both cases

$$x^2+y^2=1 \implies 3y^2+y^2=1\implies y=\pm \frac12 \quad x=\pm \frac {\sqrt 3} 2$$

and the solution is $P=\left(\frac{\sqrt 3}2,\frac12\right)$.

Comment: that is the distance from the point $x,y$ (wherever $x,y$ may be) and the line.

Comment: exactly, we have to consider the constraint $x^2+y^2=1$

Comment: @MarioSOUPER I've given an hint following your initial idea, as suggested you could use the gradient but it corresponds to the method of Lagrange's multipliers. Which method are you aimed to use?

Comment: @MarioSOUPER Then you can also use simple calculus approach or this is not allowed too?

Comment: @MarioSOUPER with the constraint we have two possibilities or substitute the constraint in the function expression (and in this case we convert the problem in a single variable problem) or Lagrange's multipliers.

Comment: @MarioSOUPER The simpler way by calculus is by finding that points on the circle for which the slope of the tangent is equal to the slope of the line (the method correspond to Lagrange's multipliers).

Comment: @MarioSOUPER By gradients we need to set that they are parallelthat is $(\sqrt 3,1)=\lambda(2x,2y)\implies x=\sqrt 3 y$. By the equality of the tangents we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}=-\sqrt 3\implies x=\sqrt 3 y$. In both cases we obtain as solution $(x,y)=(1/2,\sqrt 3/2)$.

Comment: Can you write it as an answer so i can accept it? by the way i think you mean $(x,y)=(\sqrt3/2,1/2)$.

Comment: @MarioSOUPER Yes exactly! Ok I revise

Comment: One last question! Why do we take the positive values? using the graph i can see they're both positive, but without the graph, what tells us that they're positive? and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @MarioSOUPER Good question! It suffices to check directly by the formula for the distance!

Comment: @MarioSOUPER I think you also did a very good work here. You are welcome! Bye

Comment: Oh right, thank you very much for your help and have a good night!